# Magento 1.9.2.4 randomly (seemingly) doubling product quantities

Tags: magento-1.9

So for some reason magento is randomly **doubling some items**.

Some times its **one item**, sometimes its all of them.  If we **reorder from the admin**, it then shows the **correct quantity** (in this case, 24), but the customer actually ordered and wanted 12.  Any ideas where to start?

[image: Magento problem]

Answer (score 0):

We had the similar problem - some orders were with doubled total i.e. a customer ordered 10 items but was charged for 20.

Might not be exactly your problem but at least you can start with it.

In our case our custom checkout extension was adding more than 2 addresses to a quote.

We fixed it in `app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Cart.php` function `init()` around line 145 add this code:

```
    if (count($addresses) > 2) {
     for($i = 2; $i < count($addresses); $i++) {
      $address = $addresses[$i];
      $address->isDeleted(true);
     }   
    }
```

Watch for duplicate address and remove it if needed.

Of course copy `app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Cart.php` to `app/code/local/Mage/Checkout/Model/Cart.php` to follow Magento best practices.

To see what quotes have more than two addresses assigned to it you can run this SQL query:

```
select quote_id from  sales_flat_quote_address group by quote_id having count(address_id) > 2;
```

If output is non empty you have people now in your site having double checkout sums.

Go through every quote and delete unneeded addresses keeping only two per quote: one shipping and one billing.